# MongoDB shell query on timestamp range not working in java

Tags: java, mongodb

The following query in the mongoDB shell

```
   db.getCollection('Consolidated Records').find({'timestamp': {$gte: 1500000036316, $lte:1500001136316}})
```

is working and returns several records.

The same query in Java as follows:

```
long firstTimestamp = 1500000036316L;
long lastTimestamp = 1500001136316L;     
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("timestamp", new BasicDBObject("$gte", firstTimestamp).append("$lte", lastTimestamp));
DBCursor oneDayCursor = collection.find(query);
```

doesn't return any results when called on the same DB collection.

Any idea what is wrong with the Java code?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of MongoDB ?

If you are using 3.x you could use below code

```
FindIterable<Document> findCursor = newCol.find(Filters.and(
                    Filters.gte("firstTimestamp", firstTimestamp),
                    Filters.lte("lastTimestamp ", lastTimestamp )));
```